# How do I serve static images from the same heroku server using django

Tags: django, heroku, static-files

I got my app on heroku and When I was developing locally all my images would display. But when I deployed it, my images were broken. I followed a tutorial and it didn't explain what would happen in deployment. I've read the docs for two days and to be honest it isn't that clear. People and the docs keep referring to

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

but my tutorial also spoke of

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media_cdn')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

while typing this I also realized I cant play my youtube videos on my site. One problem at a time though. Does this have anything to do with my app being free? I mean Like, my dynos not being able to handle what I'm trying to do.

Comment: are you using whitenoise?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with whitenoise.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: Last night after I posted here and searched other post for answers, I went back to the site just to try and figure some things out and see what I could make work, All of a sudden the pictures showed. This morning I went back to it and one of the images was broken and the others were fine, I edited it with another picture the pic showed so I edited it with the old pic and it showed. I don't like this randomness. I'm gonna follow your advice. whitenoise==2.0.6 is currently in my requirements.

Comment: What is the purpose of MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media_cdn') and  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'? I have only seen mention of it in two tutrials do I not use this because there is no mention of it in the docs that you suggested. Am I supposed to only use STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL?

Comment: also I'm trying to serve media uploaded files, with that being said am I supposed do this {% load media from media_cdn %}?

Comment: @losee Keep in mind that whitenoise will fail if there are files missing. The good thing is that it will also happen in development.